# Store array values in object in angular

Tags: angularjs

I want to store the array values in an object like below:

```
{"newpublicareas":[{"area_name":"x",
                    "level":0}]}
```

This is what i have done:

```
getNewTopLevelS(res){

this.newpublicarea = []

res.map((j)=> {

  this.newpublicarea.push(j.body.data.areas)

})
this.entireareas.push(this.newpublicarea)
    }
```

But it is pushing in wrong format.

Any suggestions?

Comment: what is the wrong format

Comment: {0: newpublicareas:areaname:"x", 1:newpublicareas:areaname:"y"}

Comment: and how `j.body.data` is formated, what it gives, can you edit post, with source and desired results

Answer (score 1):

Check this,

```
var res = [{"area_name":"x","level":0},{"area_name":"y","level":4},]
var newpublicarea = {newpublicarea:[]}

res.map((j)=> {

  newpublicarea.newpublicarea.push(j)

})

console.log(newpublicarea)
```

Gives

```
{
  newpublicarea: [{
  area_name: "x",
  level: 0
}, {
  area_name: "y",
  level: 4
}]
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1ev6tq4w/